# EasyAdminBundle event POST_INITIALIZE is Undefined class constant

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

The EasyAdminBundle uses FOSUserBundle user manipulator to create & manage users. I want to capture the password used when a user is created to update a postfix database.  When a user is created the dev profiler does not show that any FOSUserBundle event was listened to.  The only EasyAdminBundle event was `easy_admin.post_initialize`.  The `EasyAdminEvents` class shows

```
/** @Event("Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent") */
const POST_INITIALIZE = 'easy_admin.post_initialize';
```

But an event listener with:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
...
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            GenericEvent::POST_INITIALIZE => 'onPostInitialize',
        );
    }
```

throws:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Undefined class
>   constant 'POST_INITIALIZE' ...

I thought the answer was to use a `JavierEguiluz\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\EasyAdminEvents` event rather than a Symfony `GenericEvent`.  As in

```
use JavierEguiluz\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\EasyAdminEvents;
...
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            EasyAdminEvents::POST_INITIALIZE => 'onPostInitialize',
        );
    }
...
//error occurs on the following line:
    public function onPostInitialize(EasyAdminEvents $event)
    {
        ...
    }
```

However, doing so gave me this Catch 22:

> must be an instance of
>   JavierEguiluz\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\EasyAdminEvents, instance
>   of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent given"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the simplest answer was to change the type hint as in:

```
    public function onPostInitialize(GenericEvent $event)
    {
        ...
    }
```